# Program uses XML files for database. Need to convert this to use SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql, xml

Help!  I need to convert a large C# / .NET program that uses tree structures writing to datasets, then stores all the data in XML files. It inserts and deletes from rows in the XML files.

I need to rewrite the code to use a SQL Server 2008 database instead of the XML files. How do I begin? Is it as simple as changing the adapter if I just want to use the same tables?

Comment: Could you show the xml schema?

Comment: Are you using a DataSet from System.Data and saving/loading via its XML methods?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not that simple to turn your database into SQL. Because reading / writing in a XML file is basically file operations, and SQL requires you to use a data provider and a specific language (or just LINQ if you're working with Entity Framework)

Before converting your current XML structure into a relational database, I recommend you to read this section of MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723

I hope it helps you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way that you can swap the XML back end out for SQL as long as you've been doing things with DataSets. You can create the same structure in a SQL DB, then create a strongly typed DataSet using the [DataSet Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/314t4see%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and add the SQL tables to it. This should be fairly drop-in with the exception of changing the calls that write the data to XML to update the database instead. Obviously, you'll need to test thoroughly and may find some other things that need adjustment, but it shouldn't be too bad.